# API Invocation failing: response-status 400, error: 'Missing params object in request'

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

API Invocation failing with error:

> 'Missing params object in request' with python code
> Following is the code:

```
url='https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/endpoints/generalAPI'

data='''{
    "params":{
        "startDate":"2024-03-01",
        "endDate":"2024-03-31",
        "dataSource":"sqcdp-actions",
        "filter":{
           
        }
    }
}'''

authHeader = {'Authorization': 'Bearer cc686bbb8b6046c5ac52f70561516cc9'}

# response = requests.put(url, headers=authHeader, data=json.dumps(data))

response = requests.put(url, headers=authHeader, data=json.dumps({'params': {'startDate':'2024-03-01', 'endDate':'2024-03-31', 'dataSource': 'sqcdp-actions'}}))

print(response.json())
```

Error:

[image]

Tried following things:

- data set without json.dumps
- used variable params in the data

It is working fine when invoked from Azure Data Factory

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```py
import requests, json

url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2'

data = '''{
    "params": {
        "startDate": "2024-03-01",
        "endDate": "2024-03-31",
        "dataSource": "sqcdp-actions",
        "filter": {
           
        }
    }
}'''

data2 = {
    "params": {
        "startDate": "2024-03-01",
        "endDate": "2024-03-31",
        "dataSource": "sqcdp-actions",
        "filter": {
           
        }
    }
}

response1 = requests.post(url, data=data2)
# or
response2 = requests.post(url, data=json.loads(data))

print(response1.json())
print(response2.json())
```

Output:

[image]

Whenever you do `json.dumps` on a string, it will be sent like below and raise an error if the endpoint doesn't accept it.

`""{\n \"params\":{\n \"startDate\":\"2024-03-01\",\n \"endDate\":\"2024-03-31\",\n \"dataSource\":\"sqcdp-actions\",\n \"filter\":{\n \n }\n }\n}"`